# 2 CSS texts - 1 an email addy - how can I align them side by side?

Tags: css, alignment, text-alignment

I'm webmaster of a directory site with basic CSS skills, using SobiPro on a Joomla base. Directory entries display 2 images at top - an exterior and interior photo. At times, only 1 or the other (sometimes neither) is available; so, I have a line entry that asks anyone who can supply the missing pic(s) to email it/them to me. Until our latest upgrade, this was not a problem, but now it is. Cannot get the two divs aligned. You can see an example [here](http://www.byzcath.org/new/index.php/find-a-parish-mainmenu-111?pid=141&sid=674%3aNY-Brooklyn-3-Williamsburg)!

This is what the CSS template currently looks like:

```
div.field_photos
{
    border-style: none;
    font-weight: bold;  
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 360px;  
    margin-left: 5px;
}
div.field_addy1
{
    border-style: none;
    font-color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;  
    margin-top: 0px; /* position it horizontally */
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;  
}
```

where field_photos is the intro line (select list choosing either 'interior' or 'exterior' text) and field_addy1 is the bot-protected email addy. I tried floats, but the text tried to wrap on the pics. Tried making it into a single div, using the intro text and 'Directory Webmaster' combo into a single hyperlink, but that didn't fly.

Field widths are 150px and 200px respectively with the Title length and URL length set at 200px max. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your positioning here with margins is a bit crazy. I'm not fully sure what's going on with that. To fix this issue a quick way:

Firstly, remove the `margin-top` from your `.field_photos` divider and remove the `float:left` properties from your main image:

```
<img class="spFieldsData field_sobi2_icon" src="..." alt="">

.field_sobi2_icon {
    float:none;
}
```

Then change the `display` of the two fields you want aligned alongside eachother:

```
<div class="field_photos">...</div>
<div class="spField newClass2">...</div>

.field_photos, newClass2 {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Without the margin-top of 360px to bring the text below the 300px hgt photo, the text rises to top of page and wraps to right of the photo - as you see in looking at it now.

Comment: That's why you need to remove the `float:left` from your image (as mentioned in my answer).

Comment: did that - changed it to float: none;

Comment: It's probably being overwritten by one of the other `float` properties. Try `float:none !important;`.

Comment: Are you definitely adding it to the image and nothing else? It works for me testing locally. **Edit:** I've just checked your website and the image still has `float:left;`: `<img class="spFieldsData field_sobi2_icon" src="http://..." alt="" style="float:left;">`.

Comment: got it = which put the text back below the photo, but still no inline

Comment: @NeilFoley: that's because you haven't changed the `display` type for either. Please see the bottom part of my answer.